# Boolean Difference doesn't work despite all efforts to fix meshes

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I am trying to carve a groove into an object. This works with other objects after some mesh fixes but not with this one, which was created using a surface nurbs curve (duplicated multiple times, then skinned and converted to a mesh)

The boolean difference modifier does not modify the mesh at all.

I already tried the following steps on both meshes:
Triangulate, Remove doubles, Recalculate normals (both outwards), Fill holes.

The thing I don't understand is that when I select "Intersect" in the boolean modifier to check where the overlap is, I don't get a solid object but an open one:
[image]
What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the blender file (created with V 2.78c) [Tali_Helmet.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b3835yfspr0zu3w/Tali_Helmet.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you very much. I read numerous questions on how to fix a mesh and I am 99,9% sure I did remove doubles in both meshes but there were really 8 doubles. It works now. Thanks again!